# iOS standard for applications with many inputs and little space

Tags: ios, standards

I'm making an application for iPhone with retina 3.5 and the space is too short to put seven textfields and some buttons.

Is there any standard way to do the same using less space on the view?

Comment: This chapter from my book might help: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIScrollView to add as many Controls as you want . If the number of control are more such that they crosses the limit of screen height , thus by setting the contentSize of UIScrollView you can enable scrolling in the UIScrollView and the user can easily interact with the control that are below the visible screen. Using UIScrollView is the standard method to design these type of views .

Hope it will you.

Comment: Please do not forgot to mention the answer as selected , if any answer fullfil your requirement . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use `UIScrollView` for this. And set its contentsize as per your requirement.

UIScrollView is used for this kind of tasks , If you need to use too many controls which can not be displayed in screen then add them over UIScrollView.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: hmm.. Mark this answered if it helps you.